# How to run Z3 using Xcode

Tags: z3

Can someone tell me how to run z3 using Xcode on Mac? I tried to include all the files in the project but errors occurred saying that the symbols are undefined.

Comment: They have [prebuilt binaries for OS X](http://z3.codeplex.com/releases/view/101918) as well, saving you the trouble perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

If your linker says that symbols are missing, it is very likely that it didn't find libz3.dylib, or that it found it and didn't like it for some other reason. In your project settings you need to tell the linker what it should link against (`-l` options), and where those can be found (`-L` options).